# Kubeflow Pipeline in serving model

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, seldon

I'm beginning to dig into kubeflow pipelines for a project and have a beginner's question. It seems like kubeflow pipelines work well for training, but how about serving in production?

I have a fairly intensive pre processing pipeline for training and must apply that same pipeline for production predictions. Can I use something like Seldon Serving to create an endpoint to kickoff the pre processing pipeline, apply the model, then to return the prediction? Or is the better approach to just put everything in one docker container?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely use Seldon for serving.  In fact, Kubeflow team offers an easy way to link between training and serving: [fairing](https://github.com/kubeflow/fairing)

Fairing provides a programmatic way of deploying your prediction endpoint.  You could also take a look at [this example](https://github.com/kubeflow/fairing/tree/master/examples/prediction) on how to deploy your Seldon endpoint with your training result.

Comment: It is usually a good practice to add the solution in your code instead of adding a link to it :)

Answer (score 0):

KF Pipelines is designed for pipelines that run from start to finish. Serving process does not have an end, so, although possible, serving itself should be handled outside of a pipeline.

What the pipeline should do is to push a trained model to the long-lasting serving service in the end.

The serving can performed by CMLE serving, Kubeflow's TFServe, Seldon, etc.

> Can I use something like Seldon Serving to create an endpoint to kickoff the pre processing pipeline, apply the model, then to return the prediction?

Due to container starting overhead, Kubeflow Pipelines usually handle batch jobs. Of course you can run a pipeline for a single prediction, but the latency might not be acceptable. For serving it might be better to have a dedicated long-lived container/service that accepts requests, transforms data and makes predictions.